# ARCore on devices that don't have Play Services

Tags: android, licensing, arcore

I know there are tutorials and unofficial ways to install Google Play Services for AR. While this may work or not for a particular device is a technical problem to be addressed, but is it legal?

Is it legal to install Google Play Services for AR and use it as part of an AR app for commercial purposes?

Doing some googling I found that google play services for AR comply to https://developers.google.com/ar/arcore_open_source_licenses

It is stated that it is Apache License Version 2.0. This practically should allow commercial usage of it, but what if I am installing it not officially (not from Google Play)?

and it also stated on play store for Google Play Services for AR that:

> By using this service you agree to be bound by our Google Terms of Service (Google ToS, https://www.google.com/accounts/TOS) and Google’s general Privacy Policy (https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/). This service is a Service as defined in the Google ToS and the terms regarding software in our Services apply to your use of this service.

Also, there are privacy requirements stated here: https://developers.google.com/ar/distribute/privacy-requirements

But I suppose that as long as I add
"This application runs on Google Play Services for AR (ARCore), which is provided by Google LLC and governed by the Google Privacy Policy."
in the right place, it should be ok.

Did I get it correct? Is it legal (in terms of obeying all licenses) to use ARCore on any device whether it has Google Play Services or not? even if the specific device is officially unsupported?